# How can I increment a pandas dataframe index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, increment

If I have a variable set to a value from a pandas dataframe, how can I increment the index so that the value of my variable will change to the next incremented index?

[numbers.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNreJ.png)

Ex.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('numbers.csv')

a = df.iloc[0, 1] ## a = 3.5

#if the sky is blue, then increment index by 1

a = df.iloc[1, 1] ## a = 3.4
```

I have tried to find a way to do this and tried many things but can't find a direct approach.
I am new to Python and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I properly understand the scope of your question, but aside from the hardcoded way you've shown, if it were me I'd store the value of the index I want to increment in a variable, increment that variable, and then set my value. Like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('numbers.csv')
i = 0
a = df.iloc[i, 1]

if CONDITION:
    i = i + 1
    a = df.iloc[i, 1]
```

For something a little fancier but more confusing, Python's [Lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) can contain multiple data types, so we can bundle the actual data with its index. Like:

```
#a[1] represents the x index in the dataframe
a = [df.iloc[0, 1], 0]

if CONDITION:
    a[0] = df.iloc[a[1]+1, 1]
    a[1] = a[1] + 1
```

Both of these have the disadvantage of a new variable to maintain and keep in-sync, but they should work if I understand your question properly.

Comment: This is what I am looking for!  I can now see that I was over complicating it in my head...thank you for clearing that up for me.